# Asp.Net Identity 2.0 UserManager.RemoveClaim throws Collection was modified exception

Tags: asp.net-identity

I'm implementing a specialized User maintenance system using the Entity Framework Implementation of Asp.Net Identity (2.0).

I have one user property that is implemented with Claims.  When I try to edit it, I'm doing a

```
UserManager.RemoveClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim(claimType, oldClaimValue));
```

followed by a

```
UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user.Id, new Claim (claimType, newClaimValue));
```

The RemoveClaim call is throwing an InvalidOperationException - "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute".

Looking at the code for the UseStore.RemoveClaimAsync method (which actually ends up getting called by the state machine in UserManager) using Reflector, you can very definitely see that it's going to throw that exception.

In Reflector's rendering,it looks like this:

```
foreach (TUserClaim local in enumerable)
{
    this._userClaims.Remove(local);
}
```

but, looking above, there are two branches in which enumerable is constructed, and in one of them, it is constructed from this._userClaims.  So,if you modify this._userClaims, you're modifying the collection that is being enumerated.

I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to remove a user claim.  I'm sure this is not that uncommon an operation, so I'm amazed that I have not been able to discover anything relevant to this issue by googling.

I have also tried doing it by

```
user.Claims.Remove(new IdentityUserClaim() { ClaimType = claimType, ClaimValue= oldClaimValue,  UserId = user.Id});
UserManager.Update(user);
```

But that throws an unexplained Validation error on the Update (UserId is a required field - but there is no UserId in the user object, and all of the sub-objects that do have a userId field are either empty lists, or the UserId is set.)

Has anybody encountered this, or does anyone have any pointers to other resources that might help me solve it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try updating to 2.2.1.I think this problem have been fixed.